# Can't boot, booting filesystem error. help

Tags: boot, 20.04, lenovo, amd-ryzen

I just can't start Ubuntu.
All I get is shown in the immages.
Please help!
I tried the recovery mode but just the same.
What is "initrams"?
I've being using it for a week, sometimes with problems fot booting but never as this.
[image]

Comment: Try disabling secure boot in the BIOS

Comment: It is already disabled.